# Varnish purge configuration causing startup errors

Tags: caching, varnish, purge

I'm having a problem with the purge configuration in Varnish. I have a purge URL configured as below, but on attempting to start the service I get an error, also below. If I comment out this piece of config, the service starts without issue. Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Cheers.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #purge all
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    if (req.url ~ "varnish/index/purgeall/key/#Fj1nzljh") {
      purge_hash( ".*" );
    }
  }
```

The error message on start reads:

```
user@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo service varnish start
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                    [fail] 
storage_file: filename: /var/lib/varnish/ubuntu/varnish_storage.bin size 1024 MB.
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
(input Line 18 Pos 7)
      purge_hash( ".*" );
------##########---------
Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed
mark@ubuntu:/var/www$ sudo service varnish start
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                                                                                                                                     [fail] 
storage_file: filename: /var/lib/varnish/ubuntu/varnish_storage.bin size 1024 MB.
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
(input Line 18 Pos 7)
      purge_hash( ".*" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this in 3.0.x is something like this:

```
acl our_lan {
    "localhost";
    "10.0.0.0"/8;
    "192.168.0.0"/16;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # ...
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (! (client.ip ~ our_lan)) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }
    # ...
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        error 200 "OK: but URL not in cache.";
    }
}
```

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

purge_hash seems to have been removed in latest versions of varnish http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/changeset/e20226fa977bb3e05d49b4e497a0b9f64ca5f272

it seems that you want to clear the whole cache, you can achieve it with the other purge functions

Comment: What was called purge in 2.1 is called bans in 3.0. OP can use ban() for this. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html .